# Can't connect to mongo on EC2 Linux

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can't connect to my mongo instance running on the free tier AWS Amazon Linux 2 AMI.  I've followed several pages online and I can confirm what I've done, yet I'm not able to connect to mongo remotely.

- EC2 (with mongo installed) has a public IP
- Security group (inbound) assigned with port = 27017, protocol = tcp
- I can SSH onto the EC2 (and connect to mongo, SSH command shown below)
- I've commented out the bind setting in the /etc/mongod.conf file (see example below)
- restart the mongo service, command below
- local machine - I can ping the EC2 public IP successfully
- local machine - I try connecting to the EC2 using the terminal with "mongo 1.1.1.1" and I get the "connection failed message"

Is there anything else I can try?
Thanks

**SSH command**

```
ssh -i my-key.pem ec2-user@ec2-1-1-1-1.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**changed mongo binding setting**

```
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

**Restart mongo**

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

**Update - inbound rules**

[image: inbound rules]

**Error received when trying to connect to mongo from local machine**

```
Terminal command $ mongo 1.1.1.1

[js] Error: couldn't connect to server 1.1.1.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 1.1.1.1:27017 :: caused by :: Operation timed out :
```

**Mongo configuration file (from EC2 machine)**

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.


security:
  authorization: 'enabled'

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't comment the bindIp settings. If you comment the bindIp setting it will default to localhost. You won't be able to connect from outside network. Enable bindIp settings and set the value to 0.0.0.0.

[bind_ip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-bind-ip)

Also, check your inbound rule IP range and port(27017).

> Update the inbound rule to accept ipv4 addresses (0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: I've removed the comment so now the setting in the config is bindIp: 0.0.0.0.  I was under the impression I could connect my local machine (i.e. using robo 3T etc..) to connect to the AWS mongo.  Sounds like you can only do that with a jump box

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the inbound rules if that helps.  thanks

Comment: If you are able to ssh into the EC2 instance from your local machine, you should be able to connect to AWS mongo as well, provided the configurations are met.

Comment: yes I can ssh onto the ec2 machine from my local machine - the problem im experiencing is that I can't connect to mongo that is running on the ec2 machine from my local machine - assuming that should be possible(?)

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Try mongo --host ipaddr --port 27017 from cli.

Comment: have tried, same error (couldn't connect to server)

Comment: Or is it possible to post your mongod.conf file contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189159/discussion-between-mani-and-james).